# FFT/Guitar Tuner on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, fft

I want to get the current frequeny from an input on ios for e.g. A guitar tuning app.
The AurioTouch example is a little bit confusing, is there any good example or possibility to do this is in an easy way? I know I Have to use FFT, but that's the point where it gets confusing for me. I'm happy for any hint on which framework I have to use.
I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else that has a similar question I have open sourced my FFT guitar tuner ios app. at https://github.com/catch-twenty-two/iOS-Guitar-Tuner

Answer (score 5):

Nothing iPhone specific, but some guidelines to what you need:

- FFT is an algorithm, not a framework. Perhaps there is a library already containing the FFT-algorithm, though
- You'll need direct microphone access, with the ability to use it as some sort of "sample-stream"
- The FFT frequency result is obtained by running the algorithm over a length of samples

Quick google search on direct (live) microphone access:

- [iphone - How can i read the microphone input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593247/iphone-how-can-i-read-the-microphone-input)
- also inspect this library, seems to be abstraction of the OpenAL audio layer: http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/nice-easy-ios-openal-sound-library-open-source/

Hope it can push you in the right direction

Comment: After reading the stackoverflow link I posted again, definitely check out the aurioTouch code sample at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html  - It contains an FFT implementation ;)

Comment: Also check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873589/robust-algorithm-for-chromatic-instrument-tuner